# rectangular uibutton from a single square image

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, three20

From inspecting latest facebook and expedia iphone app, I can see the developers have used a single squared image which gets scaled up in run time into rectangular shape.

Can anyone share some code on how to do this programmatically in conjunction with the square image?

[image: I started creating 6 uiv]

[image]
 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [this](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/08/stretchable-images-and-buttons/) . Here's another one: [Stretchable Images and Buttons](http://blog.andrewmckinney.com/2010/09/28/custom-uibutton-stretchable-images-for-ios/)